# empty fields and nonexistent fields in C++

Tags: c++, field

I'm reading "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ 2nd edition" and there is this theory question in chapter 23 about fields that goes like this

> 12. What is the difference between an empty field and a nonexistent field?

The best thing I could find in the book was the information about what field is. In my words it's the way to format integer values to control how they appear on output. 
For example `setw()` manipulator can be used to change the way how digits are being displayed on output.

I couldn't really find anything in Google also so it would help me a lot if someone could drop some fast, short comment.

Or maybe I should better ask

> What is an empty field and what's a nonexistent field?

**EDIT : the chapter I'm reading is called "Text manipulation" and Bjarne is introducing regular expressions here to read the table (4 columns and lot of rows) to see if all the info in the table is matching the pattern**

Comment: What is an empty field? Is it field which is set to nullptr?

Comment: I don't know what it is and I don't recall it being mentioned in my book and also on Google. That makes it harder to answer this question. Its sometimes mentioned in the context but nothing about what it is

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding 1 thing. All I'm getting are downvotes so that might mean that this question is very stupid, on the other hand if thats so it would also make it really easy to answer but doesn't look like it is. Could someone explain to me what is so wrong with this question?

Comment: Downvote means "This question does not shown any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Read the last part. We don't want to punish you. We want to make to this question be low in search result, because probably very few people will try to find it.

Comment: I never hear about "empty fields" in `C++` before. It is probably name created by the author of the book. I can't give you answer without reading this book.

Comment: OK fair enough, but do u know what nonexistent fields are? And by the way tnx for all the comments ;)

Comment: I read your question again and it seems to me that I miss the context. I thinking about class fields earlier but this can be another kind of fields. Maybe it is something that concerns GUI. Could you place some additional informations? A piece of code would be great.

Comment: Sry for the big pause - it was a thunder out here so I had to turn off computer.
The chapter I'm reading is called "Text manipulation" and author introduces regular expressions here. After a while final example demonstrates how to write regular expression for getting info out of table of 4 columns and a lot of rows. A lot of numbers are displayed there and also some text + numbers

Comment: I still know too little. Do you the name of API?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with API (just checked out what API actually means). Hey but if this stuff is not so known to even a lot more experienced C++ guys it might be OK to skip this 1 question from the chapter's review. I would give you some upvote for helping me but I don't think I can in these comments :)

Comment: I afraid that this question is too unclear to upvote it. You eventually can delete it and write a better one. A piece of code would be really helpful. Code is always more clear than just its description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer from one other forum that 1 nice guy answered for me :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

void display_field( const std::string& text, const std::string& name )
{
    // the field that we are interested in is the marked subexpression ([[:alnum:]]*)
    // ie. zero or more alphanumeric characters immediately after 'name='
    const std::regex regex( name + '=' + "([[:alnum:]]*)" ) ;
    std::smatch match_results ;
    std::regex_search( text, match_results, regex ) ;

    std::cout << "'" << name << "' == " ;
    if( match_results.empty() ) std::cout << "  --- (nonexistent field)\n\n" ;
    else if( match_results[1].length() == 0 ) std::cout << "''  --- (empty field)\n\n" ;
    else std::cout << "'" << match_results[1] << "'  --- (non-empty field)\n\n" ;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string text = "name=etrusks email= posts=168 phone= " ;
    for( std::string fn : { "name", "email", "posts", "age", "phone", "address" } )
        display_field( text, fn ) ;
}
```

This is just an excelent answer, so happy for this :)

Output :

> 'name' == 'etrusks' --- (non-empty field)
>   'email' == '' --- (empty field)
>   'posts' == '168' --- (non-empty field)
>   'age' == --- (nonexistent field)
>   'phone' == '' --- (empty field)
>   'address' == --- (nonexistent field)